# Custom metrics in Azure

Tags: java, azure

I want to create a custom metrics with custom data for VM and cloud services operation in Azure using Java? How to create it?

Basically I need to add custom metric in Azure operation insight. I am only getting the details of adding custom metrics in the Application insight, which is out of scope for my project.

My requirement is to add the custom metrics for the virtual machine and cloud services using Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, it's a broad question, but I think there are some direction can help you.

1. If you want to collect data to help diagnose issues for your Java project using Application Insights, there are some documents you can refer to, please see [Application Insights API for custom events and metrics](http://Application%20Insights%20API%20for%20custom%20events%20and%20metrics) and [Get started with Application Insights in a Java web project](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-get-started/).
2. If you want to get insights into your Azure resource like VM or cloud services, you can refer to the [Azure Insight REST API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931943.aspx).
3. To transforming machine data into operation intelligence, you need to see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/operational-insights/ and get started via follow the document https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt484118.aspx.

Hope it helps.